# WPF ListView cursor dosen't change when resizing a column

Tags: wpf, listview

The cursor doesn't change when the mouse is in the header column to resize the column width. The column does resize, but the cursor remains as an arrow.

Does the ListView control not do this? If so, how to get the cursor to change when it is over the column resizing thumb?

```
    <ListView Name="Listing" 
                 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
                 Margin="0,0,0,0"
                 FontSize="12" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" 
                 MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick"
        >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="180">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="File" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Width="100" >
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Size" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>                        
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Length, StringFormat={}{0:#\,##0;(#\,##0); }}" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastWriteTime, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy.MMM.dd h:mm tt}}" Width="140">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Date Modified" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileType}" Width="180">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Type" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```